# React props are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

I'm very new to React, so here is my first problem.

I can't access my props in a children component.
I need to pass a function from the parent to the children,
to get Data from the Children.

Error Code in Browser Console:

> ExpenseForm.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: props.onSaveExpenseData is not a
> function
> at submitHandler (ExpenseForm.js:27:1)

I've tried to log a "test" prop to the console, but its also undefined..
so i think that something is wrong with the props..

Heres my parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import ExpenseForm from './ExpenseForm';

const NewExpense = () => {
  const saveExpenseDataHandler = enteredExpenseData => {
    const expenseData = {
      ...enteredExpenseData,
      id: Math.random().toString,
    };
    console.log(expenseData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler} test="test" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewExpense;
```

And this is my children component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ExpenseForm(props) {
  const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState('');
  const [enteredAmount, setEnteredAmount] = useState('');
  const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState('');

  const titleChangeHandler = e => {
    setEnteredTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  const amountChangeHandler = e => {
    setEnteredAmount(e.target.value);
  };

  const dateChangeHandler = e => {
    setEnteredDate(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const expenseData = {
      title: enteredTitle,
      amount: enteredAmount,
      date: new Date(enteredDate),
    };
    props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData);
    console.log(props.test);
    setEnteredTitle('');
    setEnteredAmount('');
    setEnteredDate('');
  };

+ return
```

Comment: What problem are you facing, do you have any errors  ?

Comment: Put your code in a sandbox and made it runnable; as expected it works perfectly fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-bash-nosq5y?file=/src/App.js Which means the error is in the part you aren't showing us.

Comment: I shared my error with you in the start post, but here again: 
ExpenseForm.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: props.onSaveExpenseData is not a function at submitHandler (ExpenseForm.js:27:1)

Comment: Is the test prop working ?

Comment: No, i can't use the passed function and test also don't work.
Both are undefined.

Comment: Please check if the code you have posted is truthfully representing the code in your IDE.
The posted code should work.
I'm asking this because we all have a brain-hiccup once-in-a-while and I have a suspicion that it is something like: `function ExpenseForm({props}) {...}` (where props will be undefined)

Comment: Yes, i'ts 100% the same, here is the screenshot:
https://ibb.co/SsshSq4

Its: function ExpenseForm(props) {...}

Answer (score -1):

Firstly destructure your props and then use it. Also, your expenseData is an object while saveExpenseDataHandler is a function so ofcourse onSaveExpenseData will expect a function in the child.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ExpenseForm(props) {
  const {onSaveExpenseData, test} = props
  const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState('');
  const [enteredAmount, setEnteredAmount] = useState('');
  const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState('');

  const titleChangeHandler = e => {
    setEnteredTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  const amountChangeHandler = e => {
    setEnteredAmount(e.target.value);
  };

  const dateChangeHandler = e => {
    setEnteredDate(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const expenseData = {
      title: enteredTitle,
      amount: enteredAmount,
      date: new Date(enteredDate),
    };
    onSaveExpenseData(expenseData);
    console.log(test);
    setEnteredTitle('');
    setEnteredAmount('');
    setEnteredDate('');
  };

 return
```

Comment: Yes, i know how to destructure props, but i didnt use it here for the presentation.
Why is it a problem that expenseData is a object?

Comment: You are giving const expenseData = {
      title: enteredTitle,
      amount: enteredAmount,
      date: new Date(enteredDate),
    }; object to a function that expect a function or a function reference.

Comment: Why does onSaveExpenseData except a function?

My (to the child passed) function in the parent excepts an object:

 const saveExpenseDataHandler = enteredExpenseData => {
    const expenseData = {
      ...enteredExpenseData,
      id: Math.random().toString,
    };
    console.log(expenseData);
  };

Answer (score -1):

It's working now!

My fault was that I've rendered the child component(ExpenseForm.js) in the app.js (main file) instead of the parent component (NewExpenses.js),
so I think the parent-children-connection was not there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).